# How to fetch only one value in react js?

Tags: reactjs

[api image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyLBv.png)

I want only ChannelName  value to store I try for in method but not able to store every 4 value came out but need only one to store at a time

**Index**

```
for (var x in setdata) {
    index.push(x);
  }
  Index = setdata[index[0]];
  Index1 = setdata[index[1]];
  Index2 = setdata[index[2]];
  Index3 = setdata[index[3]];
  console.log(" Index:", Index);
  console.log(" Index1", setdata[index[1]]);
  console.log(" Index2", setdata[index[2]]);
  console.log(" Index3", setdata[index[3]]);


  for (var property in Index) {
    console.log(`${property}: ${Index[property]}`);
  }
```

Comment: You should be able to access it via `resp.data.ChannelName`.

Comment: showing me undefined in console  https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-forest-tclge?file=/src/App.js **Full code**

Answer (score 0):

Index is an object, there is possibility to access its properties using dot operator.

```
Index.ChannelName
```

Here is official documentation how to work with objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ChannelName') getting this error

Comment: That's because firstly you need to get the full response, save its state and afterwards you can access the object and its properties.